# Qt 5.10.0 MySQL drivers fails to compile on Fedora 27

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, qt

I've recently updated my machine to the latest version of Fedora Linux 27 and Qt 5.10.0. The Qt framework was installed using the Offline installer qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.10.0 which I usually do. All of the options were checked during installation to ensure that all the plugins , sources, and libraries are installed. Again this is how i usually do a Fresh Install of Qt after an Update.

Now the problem is that MySQL driver is not loaded

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
```

Previously on the earlier versions like Qt 5.8 or 5.7 etc this problem was solved either by linking the correct version of libmysqlclient.so or recompiling it from the Src directory. But this is not working now at all.

So here is the ldd of the Qt program which needs MySQL

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc13709000)
    libmysqlclient.so.21 => /usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.so.21 (0x00007f59732cb000)
    libzmq.so.5 => /usr/local/lib/libzmq.so.5 (0x00007f5973045000)
    libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 => /opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5WebEngineWidgets.so.5 (0x00007f5972e04000)
    libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 => /opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5PrintSupport.so.5 (0x00007f5972b97000)
    libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0x00007f597235e000)
```

As can be seen this needs the latest version of mysql libmysqlclient.so.21 library which is already installed

This is the ldd output of /opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeb8bf8000)
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007f60cd408000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007f60cccba000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f60cca9b000)
    libmysqlclient.so.18 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f60cc715000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f60cc3c0000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f60cc1a9000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f60cbdc6000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f60cbbaf000)
    libicui18n.so.56 => /opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007f60cb716000)
    libicuuc.so.56 => /opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007f60cb35e000)
    libicudata.so.56 => /opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007f60c997b000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f60c9777000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f60c9575000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f60c9261000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f60cd863000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f60c8fee000)
```

Clearly this says libmysqlclient.so.18 => not found as because the latest version libmysqlclient.so.21 is installed.

Now when i try to recompile the drivers i'm faced with a repeated problem

```
qsql_mysql.cpp:235:9: error: ‘my_bool’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘_Bool’?
```

Here is what i did

```
    cd /opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql

/opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/mysql" "LIBS+=-L/usr/lib64/mysql"  mysql.pro

make
```

Make is failing with a strange error

```
 g++ -c -pipe -O2 -std=c++1z -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -Wvla -Wdate-time -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_NARROWING_CONVERSIONS_IN_CONNECT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_SQL_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I/opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/include/QtSql/5.10.0 -I/opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/include/QtSql/5.10.0/QtSql -I/opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/5.10.0 -I/opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/5.10.0/QtCore -I/opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/include -I/opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/include/QtSql -I/opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I.moc -isystem /usr/include/mysql -I/opt/Qt/Qt5.10.0/5.10.0/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o .obj/qsql_mysql.o qsql_mysql.cpp
qsql_mysql.cpp:235:9: error: ‘my_bool’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘_Bool’?
         my_bool nullIndicator;
         ^~~~~~~
         _Bool
qsql_mysql.cpp: In constructor ‘QMYSQLResultPrivate::QMyField::QMyField()’:
qsql_mysql.cpp:231:28: error: class ‘QMYSQLResultPrivate::QMyField’ does not have any field named ‘nullIndicator’
             : outField(0), nullIndicator(false), bufLength(0ul),
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
qsql_mysql.cpp: In member function ‘bool QMYSQLResultPrivate::bindInValues()’:
qsql_mysql.cpp:430:28: error: ‘struct QMYSQLResultPrivate::QMyField’ has no member named ‘nullIndicator’
         bind->is_null = &f.nullIndicator;
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
qsql_mysql.cpp: In member function ‘virtual QVariant QMYSQLResult::data(int)’:
qsql_mysql.cpp:641:15: error: ‘const struct QMYSQLResultPrivate::QMyField’ has no member named ‘nullIndicator’
         if (f.nullIndicator)
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
qsql_mysql.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool QMYSQLResult::isNull(int)’:
qsql_mysql.cpp:734:35: error: ‘const struct QMYSQLResultPrivate::QMyField’ has no member named ‘nullIndicator’
        return d->fields.at(field).nullIndicator;
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
qsql_mysql.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool QMYSQLResult::exec()’:
qsql_mysql.cpp:987:13: error: ‘my_bool’ was not declared in this scope
     QVector<my_bool> nullVector;
             ^~~~~~~
qsql_mysql.cpp:987:13: note: suggested alternative: ‘_Bool’
     QVector<my_bool> nullVector;
             ^~~~~~~
             _Bool
qsql_mysql.cpp:987:20: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     QVector<my_bool> nullVector;
                    ^
qsql_mysql.cpp:1001:20: error: request for member ‘resize’ in ‘nullVector’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
         nullVector.resize(values.count());
                    ^~~~~~
qsql_mysql.cpp:1008:25: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
             nullVector[i] = static_cast<my_bool>(val.isNull());
                         ^
qsql_mysql.cpp:1008:41: error: ‘my_bool’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘_Bool’?
             nullVector[i] = static_cast<my_bool>(val.isNull());
                                         ^~~~~~~
                                         _Bool
qsql_mysql.cpp:1009:46: error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
             currBind->is_null = &nullVector[i];
                                              ^
qsql_mysql.cpp:1105:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘update_max_length’
         my_bool update_max_length = true;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qsql_mysql.cpp:1114:72: error: ‘update_max_length’ was not declared in this scope
             mysql_stmt_attr_set(d->stmt, STMT_ATTR_UPDATE_MAX_LENGTH, &update_max_length);
                                                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
qsql_mysql.cpp: In member function ‘virtual bool QMYSQLDriver::open(const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, const QString&, int, const QString&)’:
qsql_mysql.cpp:1316:5: error: ‘my_bool’ was not declared in this scope
     my_bool reconnect=false;
     ^~~~~~~
qsql_mysql.cpp:1316:5: note: suggested alternative: ‘_Bool’
     my_bool reconnect=false;
     ^~~~~~~
     _Bool
qsql_mysql.cpp:1334:21: error: ‘reconnect’ was not declared in this scope
                     reconnect = true;
                     ^~~~~~~~~
qsql_mysql.cpp:1334:21: note: suggested alternative: ‘connect’
                     reconnect = true;
                     ^~~~~~~~~
                     connect
qsql_mysql.cpp:1415:13: error: ‘reconnect’ was not declared in this scope
         if (reconnect)
             ^~~~~~~~~
qsql_mysql.cpp:1415:13: note: suggested alternative: ‘connect’
         if (reconnect)
             ^~~~~~~~~
             connect
make: *** [Makefile:806: .obj/qsql_mysql.o] Error 1
```

Seriously i've been using Qt for some years now and never before did i faced this problem when setting up the MySQL drivers. And whats odd is that now the machine is updated with all the latest versions.

Please let me know how can i solve this. Been searching all over the internet for nearly a week now, but no solution for this error. Everything i tried always ends up with the error

```
qsql_mysql.cpp:235:9: error: ‘my_bool’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘_Bool’?
```

Comment: Possibly similar to this windows issue [MySQL Driver for Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42683438/qt-5-8-sql-connection-errorqmysql-driver-not-loaded-on-windows-10/45394110#45394110)

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584298/error-while-compiling-static-qt-5-10-0-with-postgresql/48584661#48584661

Comment: No stuck in the same place. Copying doesn't work. And recompiling the sqldrivers keep on giving me the same error ```qsql_mysql.cpp:235:9: error: ‘my_bool’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘_Bool’?```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally the solution have been found. I had to do a Fresh Install of Fedora 27 and this time installed the previous MySQL version which was there in Fedora 25

`dnf install https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-fc25-9.noarch.rpm
dnf install mysql-community-server`

Also installed all other dependencies. After that installed Qt 5.10.0 from the offline package as usual. Then recompiled the sqldrivers and it just went smoothly without showing any errors at all.

So i guess **MySQL 8.0** is incompatible with Qt as of now.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here by another person on the QT forums: https://forum.qt.io/topic/114022/different-versions-of-qt-with-different-versions-of-mysql

Simply open the file qsql_mysql.cpp and add "typedef bool my_bool;" just after where the initial header include definitions are located.

Then you should be good to go.