# Pyqt4 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, installation, pyqt4, ubuntu-20.04

How to install Pyqt4 in ubuntu 20.04
I have already tried all the commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools
sudo apt-get install pyqt4.qsci-dev
sudo apt install python3-pyqt4
```

But it kept on saying module has no installation candidate 
although pyqt5 is running smoothly but code is too long for changing it to pyqt5

Comment: All Qt4 and PyQt4 have been removed in the recent version, the only solution I see is to manually compile pyqt4

Comment: what about other version is it working in other version of ubuntu

Comment: @user9151679 mmm, I don't understand you, explain yourself better.PyQt4 is present in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 5):

I am actually stucked to install something which required PyQt4 on Ubuntu 20.04, the only solution I've got is to install Qt4 Library that way

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rock-core/qt4`
2. `sudo apt update`
3. `sudo apt install libqt4-declarative libqt4* libqtcore4 libqtgui4 libqtwebkit4 qt4*`

Hope that will help you a little bit more

Comment: E: Could not find libqt4-declarative package
E: The libqtcore4 package is not a candidate for installation
E: The libqtgui4 package is not a candidate for installation
E: Could not find libqtwebkit4 package

Answer (score 0):

That PPA is also missing the mysql plugin for QT4. You can rebuild it from scratch (with apt source + debuild) by modifying the apt source per these instructions: [Qt 5.10.0 MySQL drivers fails to compile on Fedora 27](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686086/qt-5-10-0-mysql-drivers-fails-to-compile-on-fedora-27/63508612#63508612)