# Unknown option -- qmake when building postgresql Qt plugin

Tags: c++, postgresql, qt, qmake

[Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qpsql) says:

> #### How to Build the QPSQL Plugin on Windows
>
> Install the appropriate PostgreSQL developer libraries for your
>   compiler. Assuming that PostgreSQL was installed in `C:\psql`, build
>   the plugin as follows:
>
> ```
> cd %QTDIR%\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers
> qmake -- PSQL_INCDIR=C:/psql/include PSQL_LIBDIR=C:/psql/lib/ms
> nmake sub-psql
> ```

So what I did:

```
D:\Qt\5.3.0-64\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers>"D:\Qt\5.3.0-64\qtbase\qmake\qmake.exe" -- PSQL_INCDIR="D:\pgsql\include" PSQL_LIBDIR="D:\pgsql\lib\msvc2010\x64"
```

What I get:

```
***Unknown option --
Usage: D:\Qt\5.3.0-64\qtbase\qmake\qmake.exe [mode] [options] [files]

... generic help follows there ...
```

So what is the correct command? I'm building this for Qt 5.3.0

Comment: It may have to do with the overhaul the Qt build system got in 5.8 that is still largely unreflected by documentation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48584298/error-while-compiling-static-qt-5-10-0-with-postgresql/48584661#48584661 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41812121/qt-lite-and-configuration-changes-in-qt-5-8

Comment: @dtech The `qmake` is `5.3.0` and so is the suorcecode.

Comment: Then it must be something else. I always build sql support together with the whole of Qt, and I've never had problems aside from the config system changes. Don't take the documentation at hearth, in the case of Qt it is quite comprehensive, but because of that it is also huge and some parts of it don't see the necessary amount of maintenance. I highly doubt it is the "" - those are only there in case your paths have empty spaces in them.

Comment: I always specify the path to `qmake` and not only call it from there from command line. Unrelated: don't use `nmake` with Qt. Use `jom`. Unlike `nmake` it uses all CPU heads.

Comment: @AlexanderVX - jom actually happened to work by accident with MinGW, up until recently when that ceased to be the case. See here https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-62947

Comment: Good to know. If and when I am back to Windows with Qt...